# How do I customize these master page areas?

Tags: master-page, branding

I am creating a custom SharePoint 2010 master page. I am basing it off of the v4.master. As part of the customization, I would like to hide the "Libraries" part, Discussions, Recycle bin.
I would like to display only custom types in the Lists section. Is there a "best practice" to do it? I tried using different content areas on my new master page, to no avail. Also, is there a way to create links for anchor tags that would have relative URLs and reference my custom types?

Comment: Please try to ask **only one** question in a question. This is the best fit for our system and means your posts will be easier to answer and find in the future. For example, customizing a master page is different to creating links for anchor tags. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.

Comment: Also, please **tag by feature** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like Libraries and Discussions can be removed from the Left Navigation via the Quick Launch menu in Site Settings.  That doesn't have to be stripped out of the master page.

The base masterpage I'm using on [my site](http://pirateeric.sharepointspace.com) has the View All Site Content residing in the Site Actions button with the Recycle Bin not being existant.  I'm using the starter masterpages from [Codeplex](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/).

To hide the view all site content and recycle bin, you want to look for this and put it into the hidden asp panel:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to have some minor design changes globally applied to SharePoint site I don't recommend messing with masterpage. Most of the branding can be done simply by overriding default `core.css` styles.

Simply create custom css file, include in it some styles for override, upload it to Style Library and then add your custom css file as Alternate CSS URL (Site Settings >  Site Master Page Settings).

Example: For hiding Recycle Bin add to your custom css file:

```css
.ms-recyclebin {
     display:none;
}
```

Don't touch masterpage if you are not 100% sure you know what are you doing. I also don't recommend using some starter or blank masterpage (at least for beginners). Much better way is to start with standard SharePoint masterpage and then apply changes by adding and/or removing content.

Answer (score 0):

To dictate what shows in the Lists, Libraries, and Discussions section you can simply go to List > List Settings > General Settings and set Display this list on the Quick Launch? accordingly.

If you want to delete those sections altogether then you need to dig into the markup a little deeper and hide thise links/sections...can get into more detail if ncessary

To hide the Recylce bin and View All Content links is simple:

```
            <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server" id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4" Visible="false">
```

Just find that tag and add Visible="false"

Comment: Eric's answer on the recycle bin is better because it catches the V3 UI.  Keep in mind that the Libraries and Discussions sections will still show even if there is nothing below them, so you might want to revisit the master page to hide those as well.

Answer (score 0):

How to Hide or Remove the Quick Launch in SharePoint 2010 working Solutions for me:

/*–Hide Quick Launch –*/

## s4-leftpanel{

display:none 
} 
.s4-ca{ 
margin-left:0px 
}

Copy above code and past it in your master page on above  to 
hide Hide or Remove the Quick Launch in SharePoint 2010

[image]

[image]

For More Info: http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/03/31/removing-the-left-hand-navigation-in-sharepoint-2010/